# Не могу понять где ошибка в скрипте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.
При выборе определенной опции товара, стоимость этой опции должна прибавляться к исходной стоимости товара. Но вместо этого пишет NaN

Если необходимо, могу дать ссылку на сайт.

Вот скрипт

```
var price = 0;    
    $.each( msoptionsprice, function( key, value ) {
        var ajson = msoptionsprice[key] != "" ? jQuery.parseJSON(msoptionsprice[key]) : {};

        $('select[name="options['+key+']"]').change(function() {
            var price = 0; 
            var priceCheched = 0;
            var priceSelect = 0;
            var spval = $(this).val();
            if (spval == 0) return false;

            $.each( msoptionsprice, function( key, value ) {
                var ajson = msoptionsprice[key] != "" ? jQuery.parseJSON(msoptionsprice[key]) : {};
                $.each( $('input[name^="options['+key+']"]:checkbox:checked'), function( key, value ) {
                    if ($(this).attr('data-count')) {
                        priceCheched += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']) * parseInt($(this).attr('data-count'));
                    } else {
                        priceCheched += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']);
                    }
                });
                $.each( $('input[name="options['+key+'][]"]:radio:checked'), function( key, value ) {
                    if (ajson[$(this).val()]) {
                        priceCheched += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']);
                    }
                });
                $.each( $('select[name="options['+key+']"] option:selected'), function( key, value ) {
                    if (ajson[$(this).val()]) {
                        priceSelect += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']);
                    }
                });
                price = parseInt(priceCheched) + parseInt(priceSelect); 

            });
            $('.pr_change').html(parseInt(price));
        });

        $('input[name^="options['+key+']"]').change(function() {
            var price = 0;   
            var priceCheched = 0;
            var priceSelect = 0;
            var spval = $(this).val();
            if (spval == 0) return false;

            $.each( msoptionsprice, function( key, value ) {

                var ajson = msoptionsprice[key] != "" ? jQuery.parseJSON(msoptionsprice[key]) : {};

                $.each( $('input[name^="options['+key+']"]:checkbox:checked'), function( key, value ) {
                    if (ajson[$(this).val()]) {
                        if ($(this).attr('data-count')) {
                            priceCheched += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']) * parseInt($(this).attr('data-count'));
                        } else {
                            priceCheched += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $.each( $('input[name="options['+key+'][]"]:radio:checked'), function( key, value ) {
                    if (ajson[$(this).val()]) {
                        priceCheched += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']);
                    }
                });
                $.each( $('select[name="options['+key+']"] option:selected'), function( key, value ) {
                    if (ajson[$(this).val()]) {
                        priceSelect += parseInt(ajson[$(this).val()]['price']);
                    }
                });

                price = parseInt(priceCheched) + parseInt(priceSelect); 
            });
            $('.pr_change').html(parseInt(price));
        });

        $('span.minus, span.plus').click(function() {
            var input = $(this).closest('.count').find('input[name^="options['+key+']"]');


            if ( $(this).hasClass("plus") ) {
                $(input).attr('data-count', parseInt(input.attr('data-count')) + parseInt(1));
            } else if ( $(this).hasClass("minus") ) {
                $(input).attr('data-count', parseInt(input.attr('data-count')) - parseInt(1));
            }

            if ($(input).attr('data-count') > 0) {
                $(this).closest('.count').find('input[name^="options['+key+']"]').attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.count').find('input[name^="options['+key+']"]').attr('checked', false);
            }
            $('input[name^="options['+key+']"]').change();

            /*$(this).closest('.count').find('input[name="options['+key+'][]"]').attr('checked', true);
            $('input[name="options['+key+'][]"]').change();*/

            console.log($(this).closest('.count').find('input[name^="options['+key+']"]'));
            //console.log($(this).closest('.count').find('input[name="count"]').val());
            /*if ($(this).closest('.count').find('input[name="count"]').val() > 0) {
                $(this).closest('.count').find('input[name="options['+key+'][]"]').attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.count').find('input[name="options['+key+'][]"]').attr('checked', false);
            }*/
        });


        /* if (ajson[$('select[name="options['+key+']"] option:selected').val()]) {
            price = parseInt(price) + parseInt(ajson[$('select[name="options['+key+']"] option:selected').val()]['price']);
        } */



    });
```

Comment: Произведите отладку: https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome Ищите, какая именно математическая операция у Вас работает неправильно и в итоге возвращает NaN.

Comment: Да, учитесь дебажить, вашу лапшу никто разгребать не будет

Comment: Я бы не обратился за помощью, если бы смог сделать сам. Сам же пытаюсь уже несколько часов, не получается найти ошибку.

Comment: Тогда приложите ссылку на сайт, так как без самих данных этот код ничего не даст скорее всего.

Comment: http://kupe.mf33.ru/katalog/shkafyi/tovar-1.html

Comment: Вроде нормально работает

Comment: Сам не пойму, работает то нормально то нет. Есть кто желающий за вознаграждение разобраться в проблеме?

Comment: Если иногда нормально а иногда нет - значит не работает. Проверяйте данные из json, где-то приходит непереводимое в число значение. Может запятая вместо точки, например, в дробных числах или типа того. Upd: с запятой parseInt сработал бы, это можно не проверять)